# Electron - mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript() with a file instead of text

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm building an application where I can't use a `webview` since it can't do everything I would like, whereas using the `mainWindow` does.

However, I need to use a whole javascript file rather than just text.

**Example:**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 1024
    });
    mainWindow.loadURL("https://www.google.com/");
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('alert("this is a test!");');

    // I want to load an entire file for the .executeJavaScript()
    // I have a file within the same directory called 'index.js'
    // How would I implement this?
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('???');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about reading the file to a string and executing it?

```
const fs = require("fs");

const js = fs.readFileSync('./somefile.js').toString();

mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(js);
```

Comment: Okay, tried that and didn't work. So I tried it with just a really simple file that contains just `alert("test")`, but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I wrote the `js` variable to a file on my Desktop just to test and it's not empty by the way.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same requirement and here is how i got it done , after npm installing xmlhttprequest use the following snippet to execute scripts from files using executeJavaScript method

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var scriptDirectory='file://' + __dirname + "/scripts/script-ext.js"  //given that the scripts folder exists in your project's parent directory 
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET",scriptDirectory,false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
   if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
       var allText = rawFile.responseText;
       console.log(allText) //this will log your script file code content to be executed
       mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(allText)
           }
        }
     }
        rawFile.send(null);
```